# Getting user type in mvc using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, model-view-controller

I am trying to verify if a user belongs to the Admin group. If he/she does, the admin page can be visible from the browser. So far I have this:

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.Session["userName"] != null && !Session["userName"].Equals(""))
{
   <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("AdminPage")">Admin page</a>
}
```

It works as it is supposed to, displays this route only for people that are logged in, but what about checking the type and allowing only admin users to see it? I also have this method in my userDB.

```
public string getType(string username) {
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
        var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("SearchForKnowledge");
        var coll = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Users");

        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("userName",username);
        var results = coll.Find(filter).ToList().First();
        return results["type"].ToString();
    }
```

It just returns the type of the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the getType method by passing the user name as parameter. If return value of getType is Admin then redirect the users to admin page.

```
string userName= (string)(Session["userName"]);
string result = getType(userName);
if (result == "Admin")
  //... redirect the user
```